# Вывод информации об отдельном товаре

Tags: ajax, php

Стоит задача: при клике на товар появляется всплывающий блок с подробной информацией об этом товаре. Как грамотно реализовать вывод подробной информации? Возникла такая идея: в блоке с краткой информацией хранить скрытое поле с id этого товара из базы, при клике по этому блоку берется этот id, посылается ajax-запрос на сервер, где делается sql-запрос, который берет всю необходимую информацию о товаре, соответствующего этому id, и возвращает клиенту. Является ли такой подход нормальным и какие есть еще варианты?

**UPDATE**
Появилась другая идея: выводить сразу всю информацию, передавать её в шаблон и те данные, которые нужны только для подробной информации хранить в скрытых полях (или в одном скрытом блоке). При клике на отдельный товар, берется информация из этих скрытых полей и вставляется в блок с подробной инфой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианта 2.

Первый: формировать блоки с подробной информацией о товаре сразу (дописать код выгребающий информацию из БД, передачу в шаблонизатор и подправить сам html шаблон) и делать их скрытыми. По клику делать видимым.

Второй: как Вы и подумали. Посылать id товара php скрипту через Ajax и в нём формировать блок с доп. информацией.

В первом случае вся информация выгребается один раз и при правильной оптимизации скорость формирования страницы увеличиться ненамного. В зависимости от количества товаров, подробной информации и html-css вёрстки - будет увеличиваться вес страницы, что тоже влияет на скорость загрузки.

Во втором случае к серверу при большой посещаемости будет много мелких запросов. Что может негативно сказаться на производительности сайта в целом.

Что Вам больше нравится то и используйте, предварительно попробовав и протестировав оба варианта. 
Может кто то ещё предложит интересный вариант. Буду следить за темой.

Comment: Первый, как я понял, соответствует последнему описанному мной. То есть, каждому товару в разметке будет соответствовать скрытый блок с подробной информацией об этом товаре? Не слишком большой перегруз разметки будет? Предполагается, что сайт будет не особо посещаемым. И что в таком случае скажете по поводу вывода с помощью аякса?

Comment: Нагрузка в первом варианте зависит от html-css вёрстки. Если Ваш дизайн страницы не перегружен множеством элементов то будет всё норм.
Вывод через AJAX добавляет на Ваш сайт дополнительные проблемы. И самое главное - во втором случае все Ваши труды пойдут насмарку если у посетителя паранойя и он отключил в браузере выполнение js кода.

Comment: Если пользователь отключит выполнение js кода, он даже всплывающий блок не увидит, поэтому сделаю на ajax. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут вообще не нужны скрытые поля. Получается вы достаете данные из базы данных и вешаете их на страницу, а после этого выгребаете данные на странице, что бы отобразить их в специальном блоке. Тут еще сразу вырисовывается минус с поисковыми системами, которые очень не любят скрытых полей.
 Проще все-таки сохранять данные в переменной, а во всплывающем окне отображать содержимое этих переменных. Это достаточно несложно сделать, написав правильный класс для товара

Comment: Как я понял, вы говорите об аяксе? У меня сейчас возникла небольшая проблема - я получил json с данными о конкретном товаре. Как мне грамотно его распарсить и вставить данные во всплывающий блок? При этом хочется, чтобы разметка находилась отдельно от скрипта.

Comment: я имел ввиду PHP и сессии.))

Насчет JSON - есть отличная функция, JSON.parse, на выходе получаешь массив либо объект со всем данными. эти данные из переменных и вгоняешь во всплывающее окно.
вот ссылка про эту функцию: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Я использую jQuery, там вроде бы в функцию success у $.ajax поступает уже распарсеный json или я ошибаюсь? Собственно, как у меня происходит: я получил json - success: function(data) { /* тут обработка */ } И вот как мне внутри этой функции грамотно раскидать значения в блоке. Блок имеет такую разметку - http://jsfiddle.net/yxr9R/  и находится в отдельном файле в виде шаблона, который подлючается на страницу. Можно, конечно, получить этот блок, у него элемента с таким-то классом и вставить туда такое-то значение, но нет ли способа проще?